# How do I reference the PDF IFilter (dll) interface built into Windows to extract text and properties of a pdf document via Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ifilter, pdf-parsing

I want to extract text and properties (author, title, etc.) of PDF file.

I need to extract and parse Text from a pdf file in a classic ASP environment.  I read another post about using the PDF iFilter driver installed with Adobe Acrobat 9 which can be referenced through COM.

Is this possible? If so, how do I get started?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the COM class name or clsid, you should be able to use Server.CreateObject() to get an instance.  You should then be able to call [IFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691105.aspx)  methods on it.